# Maven defaultGoal in multi-module project to execute goals of a child module

Tags: maven

I have a multi-moduled maven project. I'd like to set a `defaultGoal` for the root project, that runs a goal of one of the projects (more specifically `spring-boot:run`).

Is this possible and how?

I tried `-pl` and `--projects` inside the `project > build > defaultGoal` block but that didn't work.

I was also thinking of the maven execute plugin, but I am not sure if this is a viable approach at all, so I didn't dwell too much into it, before checking for a possible way without this extra plugin.